# adding double quotations to a name

Tags: r

I was trying to add double quotes to a name in R and it did not work out for me.

I have a variable called X, which looks like this

```
> X
[1] BD          Rbo5s        SMA.         01m          bo.
[6] Lv          w8s          it           2s           ds          
[11] J.t        r.Dt         2i.          J_D          32i.        
[16] V          tpMin3_Bh.s. T1m          R8m          o8m         
[21] m          wM12_AEA.dm. A3i          R8m          28s
```

I have a big matrix (file1) and I was trying to find the columns that has the colnames as in "X" and save them in (file2).

Now I am using this command, and it is not working

```
file2 = file1[,X]
```

I thought adding a double quotation would solve this problem (would it?), but i failed typing in the command for this.
Help needed! :)

Thanks,

Comment: "I thought adding a double quotation would solve this problem (would it"? but did you do it ?

Comment: Yes. I introduced a new vector " Z <- c("BD","Rbo5s","SMA.","01m") and it did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X should be a vector of characters.

```
R> X = c("BD","Rbo5s", "SMA.", "01m")
R> X
[1] "BD"    "Rbo5s" "SMA."  "01m"
```

When you display your X it has the format:

```
> X
[1] BD          Rbo5s        SMA.         01m          bo.
```

-- with no quotes, meaning that this isn't a character vector. Fix that and the indexing should work.

Comment: Yep exactly, that's what i want to do. What command do you suggest to turn the whole thing into a character vector?

Comment: I don't know where you got them from. Are they factors perhaps? In any case, try ``as.character(X)``.